# How to get Html.ActionLink to give back non querystring link?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, helper

whenever I use Html.ActionLink it always gives me the parameter as ? instead of it being apart of the url.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Username = (string)item.username })
```

Gives me:

```
/Edit?Username=username
```

Instead of:

```
/Edit/Username
```

like I have it defined in my controller.

Can anyone tell me how to get the other way? The instead of way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to register a route in `global.asax` to define your `Username` parameter:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "EditStuff",
        "{controller}/{action}/{Username}",
        new { controller = "YourControllerName", action = "Edit" }
    );

    // the default
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) for these things, with it you can decorate your controller with the actual path, like so:

```
[GET("/Edit/{Username}")]
public ActionResult Edit(string Username)
```